# Plotting a datable with multiple columns (all 1:7 rows) via ggplot with a single geom_point() using aesthetics to color them differently

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, datatable, microbenchmark

I intend to compare timings between two algorithm-based functions f1,f2 via microbenchmark which work on a rpois simulated dataset with sizes of: [1:7] vector given by 10^seq(1,4,by=0.5) i.e. :

```
[1]    10.00000    31.62278   100.00000   316.22777  1000.00000  3162.27766 10000.00000
```

Am working on to plot them as well, with all of the information required from microbenchmark (i.e. min,lq,mean,median,uq and max - yes all of them are required, except for expr and neval). I require this via ggplot on a log-log scale with a single geom_point() and aesthetics with each of the information being of different colours and here is my code for that:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)  
require(dplyr)  
library(data.table)

datasetsizes<-c(10^seq(1,4,by=0.5))

f1_min<-integer(length(datasetsizes))
f1_lq<-integer(length(datasetsizes))
f1_mean<-integer(length(datasetsizes))
f1_median<-integer(length(datasetsizes))
f1_uq<-integer(length(datasetsizes))
f1_max<-integer(length(datasetsizes))

f2_min<-integer(length(datasetsizes))
f2_lq<-integer(length(datasetsizes))
f2_mean<-integer(length(datasetsizes))
f2_median<-integer(length(datasetsizes))
f2_uq<-integer(length(datasetsizes))
f2_max<-integer(length(datasetsizes))

for(loopvar in 1:(length(datasetsizes)))
{
  s<-summary(microbenchmark(f1(rpois(datasetsizes[loopvar],10), max.segments=3L),f2(rpois(datasetsizes[loopvar],10), maxSegments=3)))

  f1_min[loopvar]    <- s$min[1]
  f2_min[loopvar]    <- s$min[2]
  f1_lq[loopvar]     <- s$lq[1]
  f2_lq[loopvar]     <- s$lq[2]
  f1_mean[loopvar]   <- s$mean[1]
  f2_mean[loopvar]   <- s$mean[2]
  f1_median[loopvar] <- s$median[1]
  f2_median[loopvar] <- s$median[2]
  f1_uq[loopvar]     <- s$uq[1]
  f2_uq[loopvar]     <- s$uq[2]
  f1_max[loopvar]    <- s$max[1]
  f2_max[loopvar]    <- s$max[2]
}

 algorithm<-data.table(f1_min ,f2_min,
                  f1_lq, f2_lq,
                  f1_mean, f2_mean,
                  f1_median, f2_median,
                  f1_uq, f2_uq,
                  f1_max, cdpa_max, datasetsizes) 

ggplot(algorithm, aes(x=algorithm,y=datasetsizes)) + geom_point(aes(color=algorithm)) + labs(x="N", y="Runtime") + scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log10') + scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10')
```

I debug my code at each step and uptil the assignment of computed values to a datatable by the name of 'algorithm' it works fine.
Here are the computed runs which are passed as [1:7]vecs into the data table along with datasetsizes (1:7 as well) at the end:

```
> algorithm
            f1_min      f2_min          f1_lq       f2_lq          f1_mean     f2_mean     f1_median f2_median                 f1_uq       f2_uq          f1_max      f2_max datasetsizes
1:       86.745000   21.863000     105.080000   23.978000       113.645630   24.898840         113.543500   24.683000     120.243000   25.565500      185.477000   39.141000     10.00000
2:      387.879000   52.893000     451.880000   58.359000       495.963480   66.070390         484.672000   62.061000     518.876500   66.116500      734.149000  110.370000     31.62278
3:     1608.287000  341.335000    1845.951500  382.062000      1963.411800  412.584590        1943.802500  412.739500    2065.103500  443.593500     2611.131000  545.853000    100.00000
4:        5.964166    3.014524       6.863869    3.508541         7.502123    3.847917           7.343956    3.851285       7.849432    4.163704        9.890556    5.096024    316.22777
5:       23.128505   29.687534      25.348581   33.654475        26.860166   37.576444          26.455269   37.080149      28.034113   41.343289       35.305429   51.347386   1000.00000
6:       79.785949  301.548202      88.112824  335.135149        94.248141  370.902821          91.577462  373.456685      98.486816  406.472393      135.355570  463.908240   3162.27766
7:      274.367776 2980.122627     311.613125 3437.044111       337.287131 3829.503738         333.544669 3820.517762     354.347487 4205.737045      546.996092 4746.143252  10000.00000
```

The microbenchmark computed values fine as expected but the ggplot throws up this error:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.table/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (7): colour, x
```

Am not being able to resolve this, can anyone let me know what is possibly wrong and correct the plotting procedure for the same?

Also on a sidenote I had to extract all the values (min,lq,mean,median,uq,max) seperately from the computed benchmark seperately since I cant take that as a datatable from the summary itself since it contained expr (expression) and neval columns. I was able to eliminate one of the columns using

`algorithm[,!"expr"] or algorithm[,!"neval"]`

but I can't eliminate two of them together, i.e.

`algorithm[,!"expr",!"neval"] or algorithm[,!("expr","neval")] or algorithm[,!"expr","neval"]` 
- all possible combinations like that don't work (throws 'invalid argument type' error).

Any possible workaround or solution to this and the plotting (main thing) would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies mainly with the fact that you're referring to an `algorithm` column in the ggplot formula that does not exist in your object.

From what you gave, I could do the following :

```
algorithm$algorithm <- 1:nrow(algorithm)

ggplot(algorithm, aes(x=algorithm,y=datasetsizes)) + geom_point(aes(color=algorithm)) + labs(x="N", y="Runtime") + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log10') + scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10')
```

and plot this fine :

[image]

**EDIT : let's clean this up a bit...**

As per OP's request, I've cleaned up his code a bit.

There are  a lot of things you can work on to improve on your code's readability, but I'm focusing more on the practical aspect here.
Basically, join your variables together in a table if you know they'll end up as such. 
There are a bunch of tricks you can use to assign the values to the correct spots, a few of which you'll see in the code below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)  
require(dplyr)  
library(data.table)

datasetsizes<-c(10^seq(1,4,by=0.5))
l <- length(datasetsizes)

# make a vector with your different conditions
conds <- c('f1', 'f2')

# initalizing a table from the getgo is much cleaner 
# than doing everything in separate variables
dat <- data.frame(
  datasetsizes = rep(datasetsizes, each = length(conds)), # make replicates for each condition
  cond = rep(NA, l*length(conds))
  )
dat[, c("min", "lq", "mean", "median", "uq", "max")] <- 0
dat$cond <- factor(dat$cond, levels = conds)
head(dat)



for(i in 1:l){ # for the love of god, don't use something as long as 'loopvar' as an iterative 
  # I don't have f1 & f2 so I did what I could...
  s <- summary(microbenchmark(
    "f1" = rpois(datasetsizes[i],10),
    "f2" = {length(rpois(datasetsizes[i],10))}))

  dat[which(dat$datasetsizes == datasetsizes[i]), # select rows of current ds size
      c("cond", "min", "lq", "mean", "median", "uq", "max")] <- s[, !colnames(s)%in%c("neval")]
}

dat <- data.table(dat)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=datasetsizes,y=mean)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = cond)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = cond)) + # added to see a clear difference btw conds
  labs(x="N", y="Runtime") + scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log10') + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10')
```

This give the following plot.

[image]

Comment: I just realized this! thanks man, upvoted. can you suggest a possible way to fit the microbenchmarking summary excluding columns 'expr' and 'neval' as the data table?

Comment: Yes : convert to a dataframe first. *e.g* `data.table(data.frame(summary(mb)))`

Comment: Also please accept the answer if this solves your issue.

Comment: Ah I realize I gave you a way to convert the summary to a datatable, but to exclude the columns specifically, you can do `algorithm[, !colnames(algorithm)%in%c("expr", "neval")] `

Comment: Ah gotcha! (was typing) and I require to plot the 2 algorithms seperately (f1 vs f2 based on points) - thats what I was looking for (sorry for the confusing terms of algorithm being the data table here)

Comment: If that's the case, you've kind of made it more difficult by separating them in different columns. You can simply keep the inital mb summary table and add a column differentiating between the f1 and f2 condition (say, `cond`). Then you can just plot with `col=cond` or `facet_wrap(~cond)`

Comment: This code actually does not compute benchmark for functions as I tried. (it gives the same output as yours for all functions with different known complexities and it usually takes ~10 seconds at min to computer uptil 1e+05) , rest of it looks pretty neat

Comment: If you look at my comments you'll notice that I put dummy functions in the mb because you did not provide them with your post.  Is this what you're referring to ?

Comment: Yes man, thats what I was referring to. I replaced them with "f1"=f1(rpois(datasetsizes[i],10),3L), "f2"=f2(rpois(datasetsizes[i],10),3) but that throws up this error :-  Error in f1(rpois(datasetsizes[i], 10), 3L) : 
  n.data == length(weight.vec) is not TRUE

Comment: the function parameters for both f1 and f2 are :(count, weight = rep(1, length(count)), maxSegments)  Eg: f1(rpois(1000,20),3L)

Comment: The error you're getting is from your f1 and f2 functions (the error message explicitly says it). I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that you have an unnamed argument *after* a named argument from what I can see. Explicitly put `max.segments = 3` instead of just `3`, like in your post and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Yes that did! (silly me, not even looking at my previous code) Thanks a ton for your help :)